# Check if a number is prime

Tags: number-theory

Is $\overbrace {111\cdots 111}^{91 \text { times}}$  a prime or not prime?? Prove your answer

Remember it is a number not a series.The number consists of $91$ $1's$.

Surely this can't be done by hit and trial but I don't know any other method of prime check. Please help

Comment: Your number is $\frac19 (10^{91}-1)$.

Comment: What do you call "by hit and trial" ? Are you ready to try all divisors up to $111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111$ ?

Comment: In general, in any base $b\geq 2$, if a rep-unit is prime, then the number of $1$s in it is also prime. The idea is that if it has $n=xy$ number of $1$s then it is divisible by a rep-unit with $x$ $1$s and by one with $y$ $1$s.

Comment: You could rewrite this as $$\sum_{n=0}^{90}10^n$$ for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number is $\sum _{k=0}^{90} 10^k=\dfrac{10^{91}-1}{10-1}=\dfrac{1}{9}\left(10^{91}-1\right)=\dfrac{1}{9}\left((10^{7})^{13}-1\right)$

$P(y)=y^{13}-1$  is divisible by $(y-1)$ therefore $(x^7)^{13}-1$ is divisible by $x^7-1$

thus $\dfrac{1}{9}\left((10^{7})^{13}-1\right)$ is divisible by $\dfrac{1}{9}\left(10^7-1\right)$ so it is not prime

Answer (score 4):

$91= 7 \times 13$.

$$x^{13}-1 = (x-1) \sum_{i=0}^{12}x^i$$

$$10^{91}-1= (10^7-1)\sum_{i=0}^{12}10^{7i}$$

$$\frac{10^{91}-1}{9}= \left[\frac{(10^7-1)}{9}\right]\sum_{i=0}^{12}10^{7i}$$

Hence it is not a prime.